# Error: Invalid hook call. while strcturing my code

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm new to React and i was trying to structure my code.
I'm building a blog homepage, so I started from the Header and it was working fine; all I did was just write the code in `index.js`.

After that I tried to restructure my code, splitting it in different files and classes and functions, I got an error about an "invalid hook call".

My intention is to build a well structured app, so I decided to split the Component logic from his appereance and his style.
I wrote an Header class that extend `React.Component`; there will be handled my component's logic.
Then i wrote a simple function that will be called by the `render()` method of the class and will return the component structure.
In the end I created a file that will contain the component style; it just contain and export a 'const' that define the style.

There it is my problem; when i try to call the function `makeStyles(style)()` i receive no log error in the shell, but my browser display this message:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Here is some code.

Header.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

import headerStyles from './HeaderStyles';


function HeaderBlock(props) {
  const classes = makeStyles(theme => (headerStyles))();

  return(
    <header className={classes.header}>
      ...
    </header>
  );
}


class Header extends react.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(props)
    return HeaderBlock(props);
  }
}

export default Header;
```

HeaderStyles.js

```js
const headerStyle = {
  header: {
    ...
  }

export default headerStyles;
}
```

I'm not sure about the error, the result that I expect is simple: just the header that I designed, with the style applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `return HeaderBlock(props);`

You are using a React Component as a normal function, wich causes `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`.

What you should do is change

```
return HeaderBlock(props);
```

To

```
return <HeaderBlock {...props} />;
```

You also shouldn't call `makeStyles` inside the functional component, you only need to call it once, but if you call it inside the functional component, it will be called on every render.

```
//     only calls makeStyles once
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => (headerStyles))

function HeaderBlock(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <header className={classes.header}>
      ...
    </header>
  );
}
```